# Push gitlab repository code to Google source repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, google-source-repositories

I followed below article to push gitlab repository code to Google cloud source repository but I'm getting an error on this command

```sh
git push -f google master

error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/project/r/test/'
```

Article followed:
https://medium.com/@bamnet/cloud-source-repositories-gitlab-2fdcf1a8e50c

Is there anything , I'm doing wrong ? Any thoughts as to how I can avoid this error message?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
src refspec master does not match any
```

The issue is the date of the article you are following: Aug. 2018.
GitLab Runner has changed since then, more precisely in May 2019.

The problem is described in [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any/24691) from May 2019:

> Since we are using refspec to clone/fetch the repository, we checkout a specific commit and not checking out a specific branch.
> When the script does `git push master`, the branch is nowhere to be found so git doesn’t know what to push.

That was because of, on GitLab side, [MR 1203](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/merge_requests/1203):

> Basically, GitLab CE/EE sends refspecs parameter to GitLab Runner [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss` `app/presenters/ci/build_runner_presenter.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/7eb24db111276a7fb7a1eac401b7f766ba08317d/app/presenters/ci/build_runner_presenter.rb#L35): this parameter is to used in GitLab Runners for fetching branch/tag refs from remote repository.
>
> This change was introduced because we wanted GitLab Rails side to leverage respecs in order for [issue 7380 "Combined ref pipelines (source+target branch)"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/7380) though, there should not be a big difference between `git clone $URL` or `mkdir $REPO_DIR && git remote add origin $URL && git fetch +refs/heads/branch_name:refs/remotes/origin/branch_name`.
> In fact, the new behavior has already run on our development project
> https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/pipelines and has no issues so far.

[Issue 4097](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4097) was opened at the time

> ### Workaround
>
> Use HEAD when you want to push this to another remote.

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - git remote add heroku https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/<project>.git
  - git push -f heroku HEAD:master
```

So don't push `master`. Push HEAD.

The [OP Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13723541/adam) uses another workaround and add:

```
before_script: 
  - git checkout master
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But still getting an error 'unable to push to unqualified destination: Master

Comment: @Adam That is because `Master` does not exist. `master` (`m` lowercase) does.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it was master

Comment: @Adam As mentioned in my answer, you need to push `HEAD:master`, not just `master`.

Comment: Yes, I did how you specified and get an error              
                                                                                             
     git push -f HEAD:master
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use
    git push HEAD:master HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: @Adam just to be sure, can you try `git push -f google HEAD:master`?

Comment: $ git push -f google HEAD:master
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/playground-s-11-936289f3/r/test'
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220675/discussion-between-vonc-and-adam).

Comment: $ git push -f google HEAD:master
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/playground-s-11-936289f3/r/test'
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: @Adam Do you have access to the chat? (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220675/discussion-between-vonc-and-adam)

Comment: I fixed it by adding below section.                   before_script:
  - git checkout master

Comment: Many thanks@VonC for your help. I appreciate it. Have a great rest of weekend.

Comment: @Adam Great! I have included your comment/solution in the answer for more visibility.